# Joining promises in angular

Tags: angularjs, promise

**How do I [join](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) 2+ promises in angular?**

(I have seen the documentation to [chain](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#description_chaining-promises) them, but that's not what I need)

Example of what I want to achieve in Q:

```
Q.all([promiseA, promiseB]).done(function () {
    console.log("Both promises have been executed concurrently and then resolved");
});
```

Comment: why does $q.all([promiseA, promiseB]).then() is not what you need?

Comment: @Michael you're right, I missed that while RTFM!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `$q.all()`

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function (result) {
// result should be an array
}, function () {
// call when either promise1 or promise 2 is rejected
});
```

Comment: Surely "either" not "neither"?

Comment: Not grammar but meaning!